# Why at increasing BPR the efflux area should be enlarged (at high BPR)?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan

I am working on a university project. I have to comment on this chart (that represents efflux area variation with the variation of the BPR).

Every other engine data are kept unchanged (turbine entry temperature, flight altitude, flight speed, compression ratios ...)

[image: Efflux area curve with the variation of the BPR]

#### $ BPR \le 7 $

It is clear that at low BPR the area of the nozzle should be enlarged in order to let the flow through at sonic conditions.

#### $ BPR \ge 7 $

What I can't explain is the reason why at high BPR the area of the nozzle useful for "swallowing" the propellant flow should be enlarged.

## My explanation (is it right?)

I think that this is due to the constant (approximately) slope of velocity decrease at nozzle exit and the progressive slower decrease of the flow.

[image: velocity at nozzle exit and hot flow with the variation of the BPR]

Is this the reason or there are some other explanation?